# Angular cli after update npm start give error

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I create application using angular cli and use backend proxy to handle backend and using polymer(vaadin) it work correctly until I update to angular cli 1.0.0-beta.22 it give Error

```
Tried to find bootstrap code, but could not. Specify either statically analyzable bootstrap code or pass in an entryModule to the plugins options.
```

**proxy.conf.json**

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

**main-polymer.ts**

```
document.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', () => {
  require('./main.ts');
});
```

**main.ts**

```
import './polyfills.ts';

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppModule } from './app/';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

// platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

how can I correct this?.

Comment: Look similar to this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2887 Have you tried the solution provided with the eventListener?

Comment: I want to use addEventListener to map backend. how I'm gone use that solution ?.

Comment: Problem still exists in 1.0.0-beta.24.

Comment: try with workaround in 2nd reply

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is caused by `Angular CLI` latest update. In the latest update, webpack searches for boostrap Module in `main.ts` top level. In `main-polymer.ts`, `main.ts` is wrapped by `addEventListener` so webpack can't find the bootstrap module that's why it reports an error.

Further reference [github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2887](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2887)

Answer (score 2):

Using github I have found a workaround that is work for me I remove the main-polymer.ts file and edited the main ts file as below.

**main.ts**

```
import './polyfills.ts';

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppModule } from './app/';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

var webComponentsFlag = false;
document.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady',() =>{
  if (!webComponentsFlag)
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
  webComponentsFlag = true;
});
if (webComponentsFlag)
 platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

and it worked for me. but can't build using ng build to overcome this problem refer the

[github issue](https://github.com/vaadin/angular2-polymer/issues/86)

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that it sometimes happens when you have an invalid import statement!  if for some reason you have deleted a component and you left the import there, then it will give you:

"Tried to find bootstrap code, but could not. Specify either statically analyzable bootstrap code or pass in an entryModule to the plugins options."

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, what I did is go back to 1.0.0-beta.21 and it work again :)